# Javascript function statement

Tags: javascript, function

I saw a function statement like this:

```
(function(){
     return new Object();
 })();
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT means create an anonymous function and call it. One called it will return an object of Object. This type of functions are mostly written for some initialization tasks.

```
(function(){

    // do some init work here...
 })();
```